# Power mode gets constantly reset to "Balanced Power"

Tags: power-management, configuration, 21.10, reset

On Ubuntu 21.10, after selecting the "Power Saver" power mode, the setting is eventually reset back to "Balanced Power" after approximately 15 minutes:

[image: power mode setting screenshot]

Using `powerprofilesctl set power-saver` results in the same effect.

My laptop is plugged in and being charged, but I am not sure if that should override my decision of using power saving mode. I do not have other power management software/packages installed.